# QTR-8RC Reflectance Sensor Array not returning data

Tags: python

I purchased a QTR-8RC Reflectance Sensor Array and now trying to configure it with Python. I am trying to determine the rate of decay of the voltage that is being read by my receivers (phototransistors) so that I know when a line is being detected. I don't know why my Python code isn't returning anything. Not even a warning statement. Additional information includes that by default the GPIO is an output and the LEDs are ON. Any help is appreciated!

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

def Read():

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.OUT)
    sleep(0.01)
    count = 0
    GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN)
    while GPIO.input(5) == True:
        count = count + 1
    return count

while True:
    Read()
    print(Read())
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: Step one when debugging is to put `print` everywhere, to find out what the values are and where things might be getting stuck, but I don't see any.

Comment: Do you need to set a pullup/pulldown for the pin?

Comment: I took a quick look at the QTR-8RC datasheet, and I see that it has one input, and eight outputs - I have no idea what you think you can accomplish with only a single GPIO pin.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any knowledge about  QTR-8RC Reflectance Sensor Array.
But looking at your python code, the problem might be with

```
while GPIO.input(5) == True
```

If the value is always true then the line with the return statement is never reached.

You could use print statement after while block to check that. Something like

```
while GPIO.input(5) == True:
    count = count + 1
print "while loop has ended" 
return count
```

Comment: I added a {print str(count)} after my {count = count + 1} statement. I am seeing that the while statement continues indefinitely; i.e. {GPIO.input(5)  == True} always. I tried to set up the GPIO as an input to heighten the impedance which should eventually make the statement false, however that's clearly not happening

Comment: You are using same channel for input and output. You could try using separate channels to determine whether it makes any difference or not.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running the program continuously run it for some time and check the outputs.
And may be you need to **increase the sleep time** to see the output practically.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

def Read():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.OUT)
    sleep(0.01)
    count = 0
    GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN)
    while GPIO.input(5) == True:
        count = count + 1
    print "count :", count
    return count




 for _ in range(100):
    print(Read())
    sleep(2)
```

Comment: The only problem remains that the {while GPIO.input(5) == True:} is always true. The count continues indefinitely, even while it should eventually fall off

Comment: @DesmondFlowers May be its problem with your sensor. try to check the input fluctuations using multi-meter. Does it working properly by hard inputs?